# Using the correct JSF scope

Tags: jsf, scope, ejb-3.1

While implementing a JSF based frontend I'm facing the following requirements:

- The user can enter statements into a textfield.
- The statements are forwarded to a server side EJB (in the same VM). The EJB stores information about each statement in collections (not in a DB) and use them while processing further statements.
- After a statement has been processed its result is displayed on the same page.
- The user can repeat this process several times. All the already processed statements must be displayed on the page.
- Several users can access the application in parallel. Theoretically the same user can open multiple tabs in his/her browser. In this case this user could enter different statements and the statements in different tabs should be processed independently.

The problem:
The ViewScoped backing beans are recreated when the user sends a new statement to the server. A new backing bean instance gets another EJB reference if I declare it as `@EJB private Service service;`. Anyway, whatever I do I think I should expect that the ViewScoped beans will be recreated while the user is using the application.

Questions:

1. Which JSF scoped backing beans should I use: ViewScoped or SessionScoped?
2. Which session beans should I use as EJBs: Stateful or Stateless?
3. How should the EJBs be referenced in the backing beans?

I'm using Primefaces 5 + WildFly (if that matters).

**EDIT**:
Entering the statement means: writing it into the textfield and pressing Enter.

**UPDATE**:
I have switched the backing beans to SessionScoped, started the application and entered a statement.

**UPDATE 2**:
The previous problem has been solved: currently I use one page + one backing bean (SessionScoped) + one EJB (Stateful) and they are working fine together. But my three questions above are still valid: I'm not sure if this configuration is the best.

Comment: Your `@ViewScoped` beans are not working as expected. A `@ViewScoped` bean should survive postbacks, moreover, it's actually the scope you need to keep your statements. Using `@SessionScoped` instead, the end user could open two tabs on the same browser and the statements for him would be the same in both (Firefox).

Comment: @XtremeBiker: Well, I'm not sure I understand you correctly: are you saying neither `@ViewScoped` nor `@SessionScoped` works?